# Event Enhancement

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am trying to figure out away to reduce how many lines our event handlers take. What is the best way to integrate the add {} and remove {}, so I don't have to keep repeating it every time I make a new event.

```
  public delegate void ErrorEventHandler(System.Object sender);
  protected ErrorEventHandler ErrorEvent;

  public event ErrorEventHandler Error
  {
     add
     {
        ErrorEvent = (ErrorEventHandler)System.Delegate.Combine(ErrorEvent, value);
     }
     remove
     {
        ErrorEvent = (ErrorEventHandler)System.Delegate.Remove(ErrorEvent, value);
     }
  }
```

Thanks to **@madreflection** the code looks like this now

```
public delegate void ErrorEventHandler(System.Object sender);
public event ErrorEventHandler Error;
protected virtual void OnError(object sender) => Error?.Invoke(sender);
```

Comment: You should accept madreflection's answer if it was indeed the answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an exceedingly verbose event definition.

The `+=` and `-=` operators are shorthand for `Delegate.Combine` and `Delegate.Remove`, plus you could put the `add` and `remove` accessors each on a single line.  That would save you some typing and a few lines.

```
add { ErrorEvent += value; }
```

Since you're not using a handler collection (e.g. the `Events` property in `System.ComponentModel.Component`), there's really no need to implement the `add` and `remove` accessors yourself.

The backing field shouldn't be `protected`.  The class that implements the event should control how it's used.

Each event can be reduced to two lines (three if you're defining a delegate type for each event but you shouldn't have to do that):

```cs
public event ErrorEventHandler Error;
protected virtual void OnError(object sender) => Error?.Invoke(sender);
```

The first line is an automatically implemented event.  It creates a private backing field for the event and all references to the event within the class use that field directly.  It also creates a public event member that can be used by consumers to subscribe to the event.  That includes add/remove logic identical to what you have.

The `OnError` method ("`On`" + event name) enables derived classes to fire the event without having to use the backing field (since it's private) and encapsulates the null-checking logic.  It's `protected virtual` so that deriving classes can override it and insert logic (such as logging) before calling the base implementation.  **Thanks to @Markus Safar** for pointing out the reason.

Comment: Actually the method should be _protected virtual_ so you can fire the event in child classes (_protected_) and change the behaviour like e.g. doing some stuff _before_ or _after_ the actual event is fired (like logging or whatever). In this case you would do your stuff and fire the event afterwards by calling _base.OnError_ (or vice versa).

Comment: I did mention firing the event in derived/child classes. Thanks for adding the part about doing things before firing the event. The more succinct form using an expression-bodied method and the null-propagating operator makes that a little less obvious. I knew there was a reason for it.

Comment: Awesome so now the code is down to three lines of code. That is definitely a step up. I still wish the invoke functionality can be built into the delegate.

Comment: @MarkusSafar: at-mentions don't work in post bodies, so a direct "thanks" to you, as well.

Comment: No problem at all, thank you for mentioning me anyway ;-)

Comment: @DotNetProgrammer: That's about is tight as it's going to get, I'm afraid. .NET does define a `.raise` accessor for events (the others are called `.add` and `.remove` in IL) but C# doesn't have a syntax for it.

Comment: @madreflection So you have to override the OnError to be able to raise the event from the parent?

Comment: You don't have to override `OnError` to raise the event from within the class that declares the event or any class deriving from that class. You only have to override it if you want to add functionality before (or after) raising the event, where the declaring class can't know what that would be because it's specific to the child class.